# Convert SQL query into Laravel 4 Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Can anyone help me convert the following SQL query into Eloquent?

```
select * 
from products, categories 
where products.productID=categories.productID and categories.categoryID = 5;
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$products = DB::table('products') ->join('categories', function($join) {
    $join->on('products.productID', '=', 'categories.productID')
         ->where('categories.categoryID',$categoryID)
} ->get();
```

Comment: Do you have Eloquent models and relations set up? Also, what have you tried yet?

Comment: I don't have models setup.  I am connecting to an existing database.  I tried this. 
 $products = DB::table('products')
 ->join('categories', function($join) {
  $join->on('products.productID', '=', 'categories.productID')
  ->where('categories.categoryID',$categoryID) 
 }
 ->get();

Comment: Other queries using only product or categories both work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably, that `$categoryID` is not available inside the closure (aka anonymous function). To be able to use a variable "from the outside" you have to add `use`

```
$products = DB::table('products')->join('categories', function($join) use ($categoryID){
$join->on('products.productID', '=', 'categories.productID')
     ->where('categories.categoryID', '=', $categoryID);
})->get();
```

Comment: When I tried the changes i still get errors.

production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)' in /test/app/storage/views/10ada48a3235fc816bfdf5ca4f491459:33
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []

Comment: There's a `)` missing before `->get()`. I correct my answer

Comment: `where` on `JoinClause` class requires all 3 parameters, you cannot ommit operator `=`.

Comment: That's right, because it's basically an alias for `on`. Thanks @JarekTkaczyk